# paragraph style in microsoft word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, styles

I am working in word 2010.
I have two different style which both of them are "linked style"

One of them is "times new roman 18 bold" we name style A.

The other one is "Calibri  15  regular italic " we name style B.

Whithin a paragraph which I styled whole paragraph to style A I select a wordand change it to style B.
why the selected word inherit Boldness  and size  from style A. but the font remains calibri and italic also. that make final selection within paragraph " calibri 18 bold italic"

how to cancel this inheritance?

Answer (score 0):

I created the styles as you described, basing my new styles on Normal (which I assumed you did).

I then applied the same styles as you described in your post; i.e., applying StyleB to a word within the StyleA phrase.

And then I tried doing the reverse, applying StyleA to word in a StyleB phrase.

I could not replicate your situation, but I did nonetheless get surprising results:

- When I applied StyleB over a StyleA word, then the selected word changed to Times New Roman bold-italic 15pt. Calibri did not appear anywhere.
- When I applied StyleA over a StyleB word, then the word changed to StyleA as expected.

This suggests that Word has some kind of prioritization for the order in which fonts are applied.

This does not answer your question but it perhaps adds enough information to the discussion that someone else can.

Note: I would have posted this as a comment but my reputation is not yet quite high enough. So this "answer" will have to my contribution.